# Javascript calculator backspace not working on first time

Tags: javascript

I am in the process of creating a calculator in javascript, and am trying to make a backspace. My initial thought was to use the `.slice` function, and it works, to a point. It works in the way that it takes a number off, but I am having trouble getting it to actually take off the number from the first value, if that makes any sense. It doesn't work on the first time, for example, if I type in 12, then use the backspace, then make the number 13 and do 13 + 6; it will come up with NaN. However if I do that same process again, it works as long as i use my clear button and not refresh the page. I have tried everything I can think of, bu't can't get it to work. Here is the code, sorry its a lot, but I figured it be better to have it all there. I am open to any suggestions, but prefer not to use jQuery, as I haven't yet learned a single thing about jQuery

Code:

```
        //Variables
        var xValue = 0;
        var xValue2 = 0;

        //Button Values
        var plusButton = 0;
        var subButton = 0;
        var timesButton = 0;
        var divideButton = 0;
        var squaredButton = 0;
        var powerButton = 0;

        //Answers
        var sum = 0;
        var difference = 0;
        var product = 0;
        var quotent = 0;
        var square = 0;
        var power = 0;

        //Functions

        function add () {
            if (plusButton >= 1) {
                xValue2 = xValue;
                xValue = "";
            }

            subButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
            //alert(xValue);
        }

        function addFunction () {
            sum = +xValue + +xValue2;
            answer.innerHTML = sum;
        }

        function subtract () {
            if (subButton >= 1) {
                xValue2 = xValue;
                xValue = "";
            }

            plusButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
        }

        function subtractFunction () {
            difference = +xValue2 - +xValue1;
            answer.innerHTML = difference;
        }

        function multiply () {
            if(timesButton >= 1) {
                temp = xValue2;
                xValue2 = xValue;
                xValue = "";
            }

            subButton = 0;
            plusButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
        }

        function multiplyFunction () {
            product = +xValue * +xValue2;
            answer.innerHTML = product;
        }

        function divide () {
            if(divideButton >= 1) {
                temp = xValue2;
                xValue2 = xValue;
                xValue = "";
            }

            subButton = 0;
            plusButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
        }

        function divideFunction () {
            var quotent = +xValue / +xValue2;
            answer.innerHTML = quotent;
        }

        function squared () {
            subButton = 0;
            plusButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
        }

        function squaredFunction () {
            square = Math.pow(xValue, 2);
            answer.innerHTML = square;
        }

        function powerNum () {
            if(powerButton >= 1) {
                xValue2 = xValue;
                xValue = "";
            }

            plusButton = 0;
            subButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
        }

        function powerFunction () {
            var power = Math.pow(xValue2, xValue);
            answer.innerHTML = power;
        }

        function compute () {
            if(plusButton >= 1) {
                addFunction();
                xValue = sum;
            }

            else if (subButton >= 1) {
                subtractFunction();
                xValue = difference;
            }

            else if (timesButton >= 1) {
                multiplyFunction();
                xValue = product;
            }

            else if (divideButton >= 1) {
                divideFunction();
                xValue = quotent;
            }

            else if (squaredButton >= 1) {
                squaredFunction();
                xValue = square;
            }

            else if (powerButton >= 1) {
                powerFunction();
                xValue2 = power;
            }

            xValue2 = 0;
            plusButton = 0;
            subButton = 0;
            timesButton = 0;
            divideButton = 0;
            squaredButton = 0;
            powerButton = 0;
        }

        function clearScreen() {
            answer.innerHTML = "";
            xValue = 0;
            plusButton = 0;
            xValue2 = 0;
            temp = 0;
        }

        function backOne () {
            var str = answer.innerHTML;
            var res = str.slice(0, -1);
            answer.innerHTML = res;
            xValue = parseInt(res);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring on the current displayed value in the calculator and replace the current value with the substring of it. The substring would be (0, length - 1).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

EDIT: should be length - 1

Comment: i tried that, but it didnt't seem to work. I did this `var res = str.substring(0, answer.length - 1);` but it didn't work

Comment: Did it return the same var? Length - 1 should work. Did you re-assign the new value to the display value?

Comment: Yes,and it still returns NaN.

This is the exact code I have:

 `function backOne () {
                var str = answer.innerHTML;
                var res = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
                answer.innerHTML = String(res);
                xValue = parseInt(res);
`

Comment: It looks like some issue with HTML the js must work I just ran it quickly it returns a string missing the last character.

Comment: I dont have a problem with getting the number to appear with the string missing the last number, what I'm having trouble with is getting that new edited number(123 instead of 1234) and adding,subtracting, etc. with that new number. It says NaN then, but only on the first time, then it works

Comment: Maybe there a string somewhere (value2?) before the operation is done. Parseint() everything before performing operations?

Comment: I  have parseInt() everything, but  it still won't work. I still get NaN on the first time, but works every time after